# import data from Salesforce to Excel

Tags: excel, import, salesforce

i want to Link Salesforce reports via get data to Excel. however there is a limitation of 2000 Records when the salesforce imports to excel.
how can i get the data directly from salesforce report into my excel without any limitation. i dont want to export separately from SFDC. as in the excel import file i already have charts linked to the data. i linked via get data, online sources - salesforce reports. but theres a limitation of 2000 records.i want 40000 records to be extracted in the linkage.

Comment: Is Excel limiting the number or Salesforce?

Comment: Sales force, can it be done via an odbc/data connector or data loader